# Setting <Window.DataContext> in XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, datacontext

I followed a very simple MVVM example as a basis for my program. The author had one code behind instruction he used in the main page to set the `DataContext`. I'm thinking I should be able to do this in the XAML instead. The MainWindowViewModel is in a directory ViewModels. The code behind works.

```
namespace RDLfromSP
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = new ViewModels.MainWindowViewModel();
        }
    }
}
```

I can't seem to find the right combo to set it instead in the XAML

```
<Window x:Class="RDLfromSP.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="300" Width="300" > 

    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:ViewModels.MainWindowViewModel />
    </Window.DataContext>
```

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 80):

You'll need an xml namespace mapping to the `ViewModels` namespace.  Once you add that, it would be:

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <vms:MainWindowViewModel />
</Window.DataContext>
```

(This is assuming you map `vms` to the appropriate namespace.)

This should look just like your current namespace mapping for `local:`, but called `vms:` with the appropriate namespace specified.

Comment: @DavidBeck Typically, when something works, you should click on the little check box next to that answer to "mark it as the answer" - this will help your account over time, as it shows that your questions get answered when you ask them later ;)